# fontawesome click doesn't work click (angular)

Tags: angular, frameworks

I want to fill star when it's empty

```html
<div (click)="selected()">
  <i [class.fas]="isFavorite"
     [class.far]="!isFavorite"
     class='fa-star'>
  </i>
</div>
```

```js
isFavorite: boolean;

selected() {
   this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
   console.log(this.isFavorite)
}
```

but the icon doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<i [class]="isFavorite ? 'far fa-star' : false"></i>
```

Comment: Hello, doesn't work :( I try this also: <div (click)="selected()">
  <i [ngClass]="{'fas fa-star' : isFavorite,
      'far fa-star': !isFavorite}"
  ></i>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```html
<div (click)="selected()">
  <i [ngClass]="isFavorite ? 'fas' : 'far'"
     class="fa-star"></i>
</div>
```

Check that you dont have any other errors in your console

Comment: Hello ! doesn't work, nothing happen :( , not error in console too I don't understand

Comment: What do you see? Have you loaded the font awesome icons?